# Replacing DIVs with modern equivalents

Tags: html, css

When I use the "classic form"

```css
    .mycontainer {
        width: 300px;
        height: 100px;
        
        border: solid cyan 1px;
        border-radius: 0.5em;

        display: flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    .title {
        border: solid blue 1px;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        margin: 2px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    h2 {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
    }
    .item {
        flex: 1 1 auto;

        border: solid blue 1px;
        border-radius: 0.5em;
        margin: 2px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="mycontainer">
    <div class="title">
        <h2>title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h2>item</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

I get the expected result

[image: title + item]

Yet when I use the modern form.

```css
        mycontainer {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            
            border: solid cyan 1px;
            border-radius: 0.5em;

            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column;
        }
        title {
            border: solid blue 1px;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            margin: 2px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            margin: 0 0 0 0;
        }
        item {
            flex: 1 1 auto;

            border: solid blue 1px;
            border-radius: 0.5em;
            margin: 2px;
        }
```

```html
    <mycontainer>
        <title>
            <h2>title</h2>
        </title>
        <item>
            <h2>item</h2>
        </item>
    </mycontainer>
```

I miss one part altogether.

[image: item, missing title]

My best bet is that this is a result of a missing default declaration for DIVs.

Is the guess accurate? If yes, then what is the declaration so I can add it manually. If it's not, then what causes the difference?

Answer (score 2):

`<title>` is an HTML element that changes the text in the browser tab. Normally it's in the `<head>`, but can operate normally even in the body.

Comment: Ouch.. I need to see why my favorite editor (emacs) did not guard me from this issue by color highlighting in its web-mode.